# need to add start date and end date parameter in stored procedure (oracle)

Tags: oracle

I want to add start date and end date parameter in oracle to show the data between startdate and enddate ,Currently date is in this format 20221003,20221003,20221003 (yyyymmdd)

```
 to_date(posting_date,'yyyymmdd') >= to_date(TO_CHAR (:STARTDATE, 'yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd') and to_date(posting_date,'yyyymmdd') <= to_date(TO_CHAR (:ENDDATE, 'yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's

```
create or replace procedure p_proc (par_start in number, par_end in number) is
begin
  select ...
  into ...
  from ...
  where posting_date between to_date(par_start, 'yyyymmdd') and to_date(par_end, 'yyyymmdd');
end;
/
```

presuming that `posting_date` columns' datatype is `DATE` (should be! If not, consider fixing data model; don't store dates in any other datatype column but `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)).

If it is a number, then modify it to

```
where to_date(posting_date, 'yyyymmdd') between <the rest is just the same as above>
```

Comment: create or replace procedure p_proc (par_start in number, par_end in number) as
begin
 select CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER, 
TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
ttr_trans_code, 
currency, 
first_name, 
trans_date, 
posting_date,
ttr_transactions.transaction_amount || SUBSTR(ttr_transactions.customer_identifier, 1, 5)as Alias 
from ttr_transactions  
  where posting_date between to_date(par_start, 'yyyymmdd') and to_date(par_end, 'yyyymmdd')order by posting_date, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, ttr_trans_code, first_name;
end p_proc;

Comment: Error(3,2): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: for above oracle stored procedure into clause is expected error ,please tell me how to solve it .

Comment: PL/SQL's SELECT requires an INTO clause. It depends on what you plan to do with data being returned, and how many rows you expect. If it'll return a single row, then declare as many local variables as there are columns in SELECT (8). If there'll be many rows, then you could process them one-by-one (in a cursor FOR loop), or fetch the result into a collection you'd first have to create.